# How can I set initial reference frame correctly using CMDeviceMotion

Tags: swift, xcode, motion-detection

I am currently working on a project where I collect the magnitude of a device's attitude (orientation) once a button is pressed, and plot this over time. I would like to set this up such that the initial attitude is set to the attitude the device was at when the button was pressed, so all proceeding values are with respect to that zero point.

I have been using this website as a guide:
https://nshipster.com/cmdevicemotion/
The final tutorial is what I am looking for, since performing 'multiplyByInverseOf' the initial attitude should do what I am after.

Here is a snapshot of my results (starting from 3 as it is a 3 second countdown):

```
time    attitude Magnitude
3       0
2.99    0.673
2.98    0.673
2.97    0.673
2.96    0.67
2.95    0.669
2.94    0.668
```

And the code I am using:

```
self.motion.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { (motion, error) in

                //START Code here runs every 'updateFrequency'

                if let data = self.motion.deviceMotion {

                    //Store initial attitude for reference
                    if self.isFirst == true {
                        self.initialAttitude = data.attitude
                        self.isFirst = false
                    }

                    //attitude of phone impacted by user
                    data.attitude.multiply(byInverseOf: self.initialAttitude!)
                    let attitudeMagnitude = self.magnitudeFromAttitude(attitude: data.attitude)
```

Both initialAttitude and isFirst are global; isFirst is used to access the first iteration of the loop only (to retrieve initial attitude).

It can be seen that the first data point is zero-referenced correctly, however the values jump (and stay steady) beyond this. How can I refactor my code to prevent this jump?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: EDIT I understand now this is a problem involving trying to modify a global variable within a preset closure. Any help would be appreciated.